# Podcasts Playing Too Fast

Tags: podcasts

My Podcasts are playing too fast. I have searched the web and there should be a 1x button close to the rewind button, but I do not see it. (See Attached Screenshot). I have a Iphone 5s running IOS 10. How can I slow down the play speed?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To see the 1x button you need to be in the Podcasts app and viewing the main screen of the podcast you're playing.

Here are the steps using the same podcast in your screenshot:

**STEP 1**

[image]

**STEP 2**

[image]

**STEP 3**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot is showing the Podcast widget.  You can control the speed when you open the app and tap the `1x` on the left-side next to **Skip Back**, see image below.
[image]